# Error while creating web application "Specified value is not supported for the parameter" in 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I am using SharePoint 2010.While creating a web application i am getting the following error :Specified value is not supported for the parameter.Some times the user credentials are asking for regularly.Please help me.

Comment: Can you supply more details.  How are you creating the web application and what parameters are you setting?  Did you look in the ULS logs for more detailed error information?

Answer (score 0):

This happens when server is not connected to the domain, at least this was the case for me having the same issue.